# How to set multi-dex in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools

I have a scala sbt android project that I have imported to Intellij. It builds fine using sbt but when I compile from Intellij I get the following error:

```
Error:Android Pre Dex: [scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar] trouble writing output: Too many method references: 69269; max is 65536.
Error:Android Pre Dex: [scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar] You may try using --multi-dex option.
...
```

I can't find any way of successfully setting this 'multi-dex' option however. In my Modules under Project Structure I have clicked 'Enable multi-dex support' but to no avail. I also tried adding the below to my build.scala but still with no success:

```
dexMulti := true,
dexAdditionalParams := Seq("--multi-dex"),
```

How can I pass this --multi-dex option to the Pre-Dex?